# node.js Path modules: use Unix path separators even when running on Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, path

I have a script, which is using standard node.js path modules 
https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

When using path functions such as 'path.relative', the path library looks at what operating system I'm on, and uses that OS's path separator.  (\ on Windows, / on POSIX).  That's cool, and makes a lot of tasks very convenient.  The problem is, the script is auto-generating some files which are intended for a UNIX platform, and need the Unix path separator.  But sometimes the script will be being run from a Windows platform.  **I need the output of the script to be the same (Unix path separators), regardless of which platform is running the script.  Is there a way to do this?**  (To make path use a specific path separator, rather than using the one for the operating system running Node?)

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use [path.posix](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_windows_vs_posix) instead of just path.

Example:

```
var path = require('path');
path.join('a', 'b'); // a\\b
path.posix.join('a', 'b'); // a/b
```

Comment: Note that `posix` doesn't solve all your problems.
For example, when run from `D:\\mydir`: `path.resolve('myfile')` (D:\\mydir\\myfile) `path.posix.resolve('myfile')` (D:\\mydir/myfile)